# What is happening at the microscopic level so that superconductors expelled out magnetic field lines?

Tags: magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

Superconductor shows perfect diamagnetism then what is happening at the microscopic level so they exhibit such behaviour? In other words why they repel the magnetic field? Why most of the good conductors at room temperature are not superconductors?

Comment: "*Why most of the good conductors at room temperature are not superconductors?*" Most? You know of a room temperature superconductor? Let us in on it.

Comment: Read through this: https://www.open.edu/openlearn/ocw/mod/oucontent/view.php?id=2685&printable=1 "Meissner effect "

Comment: @DKNguyen - That was a mean comment, unasked for. The phrasing is not perfect but what the OP meant is why most room temperature good conductors do not become superconductors when cooled. And that is true: copper and silver (pretty good conductors) do not become superconductors. Lead does. The rough reason is linked to electron-phonon interaction. Peace.

Comment: @rpsml I did not mean it to be so. It was more in jest and should have included a ;) at the end.